# How to use ViewModel 2d array property in TextBoxFor?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I would ideally like to use 2d arrays with Textboxfor like below:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Table[0,1])
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Table[0,2])
```

However I believe it is not supported as I get the error message:

```
Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.
```

The only idea I have is to split the ViewModel into multiple single-dimension arrays abit like:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.TableR0[1])
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.TableR0[2])
```

Thoughts?

Comment: A view model is supposed to represent what your want in the view. Create a view model (say `ParentVM` that contains a property `List<ChildVM> Children`) and pass a collection of `ParentVM` to the view and you can use nested `for` loops to display the data.

Comment: Thanks for this. However I am not wanting to display data. I want to be able to edit the data using "TextBoxFor". It seems that this is possible with 1d arrays by not 2d arrays.

Comment: It exactly the same for editing and display! And the only way to edit the data have get correct 2-way model binding is to use nested models

Answer (score 0):

There is an `Html.TextBox` for this case. Or it is better if you change your `ViewModel` design because `ViewModel` should meet requirements of your `View`, not `Model`.

Comment: Do you have a code example using Html.Textbox? Thanks

Comment: Is TextBox[,] textboxes; part of the solution?

Comment: @SamJolly sorry, I misundrestood a case. Your solution with an array of rows seems to be the best. I used this approach in my recent projects.